# Get text from URL txt

Tags: php, url, text

Is there any way to get a simple php code that just displays the text from a txt document, that's on a url?

This is what I've got so far. I'm sure I'm missing something~

```
<?
$text = file_get_contents('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28653637/Snip/Snip/Snip.txt');
fopen ($text)
?>
```

Guessing you can't open it, since it's not on the drive. Any workaround that, or fix you guys could help me with?

Thanks (:

Comment: file_get_contents has to be the easiest way. Anyway wanted to say; I think it's always safer to use <?php ?> than the short form <? ?>

Answer (score 7):

Too easy! :)

```
$text = file_get_contents('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28653637/Snip/Snip/Snip.txt');
echo $text;
```

Explanation:

`file_get_contents()` will return the **contents** of the remote file and assign it to the `$text` variable. Then you'll just have to ouput these contents using the `echo` statement

**Alternative**: use the [`readfile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function. It will output the contents of the file directly:

```
readfile('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28653637/Snip/Snip/Snip.txt');
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Although I still get no response! :s

Comment: @Mansl did you try using <?php ?> instead of <? ?> tags

Comment: Yes, I did! Still no use :S

Comment: add the line `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script.

Comment: No progress, if I did it correctly that is: `<?php
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
readfile('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28653637/Snip/Snip/Snip.txt');
    ?>`

Comment: I tried making a new php file, and a new .txt file to read. No file being read there. I have no idea, really. It seems like it shoud work perfectly. :S

Comment: Yes, just white... whiteness?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to open it. It's already appended as a string to the variable `$text`.

```
$text = file_get_contents('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28653637/Snip/Snip/Snip.txt');
echo $text;
//Outputs "“Why Don't You Get A Job?” ― The Offspring"
```

Comment: Just a simple song title displayer, that's easier to read, more or less what I'm trying to do :)